# How to add a button in data table flask

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, flask

i got problem with add botton in boostrap datatable. Im now in flask (python), js please give me some tips or solution i will be very gratefull.
i want do something like this.
[image]

I try return botton with jsonify data. I try change js for it. But cant found right solution.
For fill date in table js code.

Html code

```
<div class="row-90">
        <table class="table display" id="calEvents">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">GROUP</th>
                    <th scope="col">WEEKDAY</th>
                    <th scope="col">DATE</th>
                    <th scope="col">TICKER</th>
                    <th scope="col">EVENT</th>
                    <th scope="col">READX</th>
                    <th scope="col">ACTION</th>
               
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">GROUP</th>
                    <th scope="col">WEEKDAY</th>
                    <th scope="col">DATE</th>
                    <th scope="col">TICKER</th>
                    <th scope="col">EVENT</th>
                    <th scope="col">READX</th>
                    <th scope="col">ACTION</th>
        
                   
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
```

js code

```
$('#calEvents').DataTable( {
       
        'columnDefs': [
            {
               targets: 2, render: function(data1){ return moment(data1).format('dddd')},
            }, //data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"
            
            { targets: 3, render: function(data2){ return moment(data2).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}},
        ]
     
    } );
```

Please help me. (this code without bootton code, because for now idk there place it(no one solution not working so...). Please not to judge me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `defaultContent` attribute in DataTable to add additional buttons at in your table. [(Reference)](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html)

```
$('#calEvents').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": false,
    "order": [[ 3, "asc" ]],
    "ajax": "/api/v1/calendar/get",
    'columnDefs': [
        { 
           targets: 2, render: function(data1){ return moment(data1).format('dddd')},
           defaultContent: '<button class="btn-view" type="button">Edit</button>'
             + '<button class="btn-delete" type="button">Delete</button>'
        },
        { targets: 3, render: function(data2){ return moment(data2).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}},
    ]
} );
```

Comment: it does't work for me. Maybe need change html code too?

Comment: or maybe somehow give location what boottons?